# Rails 7 create pdf temp file and send it in POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-io, temporary-files

In my Rails 7 API only app I'm creating a PDF file with gem Prawn. After creation I want to save that file into `Tempfile` and then send it to the external service via POST call. To attach file into POST call I've to use `Faraday::UploadIO`. Unfortunately I'm unable to create Tempfile and pass it into Net::HTTP client.

Here is what I have:

`lib/file_io.rb`

```
# require 'file_io' and use FileIO to simplify persistence of IO stream as file
class FileIO < StringIO
  attr_reader :original_filename

  def initialize(stream, filename)
    super(stream)
    @original_filename = filename
  end
end
```

`services/mandate/uploader.rb`

```
# class which generates PDF and send it to the API

require 'file_io'
require 'net/http'

module Mandate
  class Uploader
    def send_pdf_file(file_io)
      uri = URI('test_path')
      req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
      req['apiToken'] = Rails.application.credentials.api_token
      req['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data'
      file = Tempfile.new('mandate.pdf')
      file.write(file_io.read)
      file.close
      req.set_form([['file', Faraday::UploadIO.new(file.path, 'application/pdf')]], 'multipart/form-data')
      res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, use_ssl: true) do |http|
        http.request(req)
    end

    def generate_pdf(params)
      FileIO.new(PDFDocument::Generator.new(params).render, 'document.pdf')
    end
  end
end
```

This code produces me an error:

> lib/ruby/3.1.0/delegate.rb:349:in `write': "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)

I've tried to force encode the file by:

```
  file.write(file_io.read.force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT'))
```

But error message is the same.